# Macro for adding Excel form data in SharePoint list?

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint-2013

I have Excel 2013 worksheet where user will add some data.

Excel worksheet data:
[image: Excel worksheet data]

We need to create button on worksheet (Save button) which had macro behind, which saves data in SharePoint list (already created in SP site).

List having same two columns.

I do not have permission on SQL server to add stored procedure or fire query for call from Macro.

Is there any other way? Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You can't manipulate a SharePoint list with Excel VBA. You may want to re-think your architecture. I suggest to let the user enter the data into a SharePoint list form instead of an Excel sheet.

You can export the SharePoint list to Excel, which creates a dynamic, refreshable data connection, if you want to use the SharePoint list data for further analysis.

Comment: actually users are using excel form from last 12 yrs. they want that functionality as it is. Also requirement is to adding data from new form(with look and feel) too that I did by creating new form using content editor webpart. I stuck in that functionality to add item in list from excel  sheet

Comment: Again: You can't use VBA to add data to a SharePoint list. Even if your users don't want to change and even if the requirement is that the form stays as it always was. If the requirements are so important, then you will need to invest in a custom solution for SharePoint with the Visual Studio development tools. But it can't be done with VBA.

Comment: Thanks for your confirmation. Let me confirm this to the team management.